# Calculating average of grades in Java

Tags: java

I want to create a program where I can input numbers and grades and the computer will calculate the average of the passing ones only but if the numerator or dinomenator was zero what will happened how can I fix this?

```
public class Grades {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        double grade1, grade2, grade3, avg, sum=0;
        int counter = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your first Grade");
        grade1 = input.nextDouble();
        if (grade1 >= 90)
        {
            System.out.println("excellent");
            counter++;
            sum += grade1;
        }
        else if (grade1 < 90 && grade1 >= 70)
        {
            System.out.println("very good");
            counter++;
            sum += grade1;
        }
        else if (grade1 < 70 && grade1 >= 60)
        {
            System.out.println("fair");
            counter++;
            sum += grade1;
        }
        else if (grade1 < 60)
        {
            System.out.println("you fail");
        }
        System.out.println("Enter your second Grade");
        grade2 = input.nextDouble();
        if (grade2 >= 90)
        {
            System.out.println("excellent");
            counter++;
            sum += grade2;
        }
        else if (grade2 < 90 && grade2 >= 70)
        {
            System.out.println("very good");
            counter++;
            sum += grade2;
        }
        else if (grade2 < 70 && grade2 >= 60)
        {
            System.out.println("fair");
            counter++;
            sum += grade2;
        }
        else if (grade2 < 60)
            System.out.println("you fail");
        System.out.println("Enter your third Grade");
        grade3 = input.nextDouble();
        if (grade3 >= 90)
        {
            System.out.println("excellent");
            counter++;
            sum += grade3;
        }
        else if (grade3 < 90 && grade3 >= 70)
        {
            System.out.println("very good");
            counter++;
            sum += grade3;
        }
        else if (grade3 < 70 && grade3 >= 60)
        {
            System.out.println("fair");
            counter++;
            sum += grade3;
        }
        else if (grade3 < 60)
            System.out.println("you fail");
        avg=sum/counter;
        System.out.println("your average is : "+avg);


    }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code... what's the question?

Comment: "but if the numerator or dinomenator was zero what will happen" - It's up to you to decide what will happen.

Comment: Check the numerator / denominator before doing the division.  It's up to you what happens when you find a zero divisor.  I would assume you just add 1 to the number of grades and it brings everyones average down...

Comment: If the denominator is zero the division code will throw `ArithmeticException`, see here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of things we use exception handling but if you are a beginner u can fix it by applying a if condition to check weather num or denominator is zero

```
else if (grade3 < 60)
    System.out.println("you fail");
if(sum == 0 || counter == 0) {
    System.out.println("Invalid sum or total count");
} else {
    avg = sum / counter;
}
System.out.println("your average is : " + avg);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that I understand your question but when I run your code I find that if either `sum` or `counter` are 0 the result is `NaN`.

In Java, `NaN` stands for "not a number". This occurs because you are trying to perform a floating point operation that can't actually be performed (or would give an answer that is unhelpful). Like dividing by 0 for example.

Like I said earlier, I'm not entirely sure that I understand your question but the best way to avoid this would be to check to make sure that the values of `sum` and `counter` are both non-zero before you perform the calculation.

So, instead of:

```
avg=sum/counter;
```

you could try:

```
if(sum > 0 && counter > 0) avg = sum / counter;
```

Indeed, there are many ways that you could check this but this is just one that would ensure that you get a useful value returned to you. Another way would be to check for this during user input but I won't go into that until I'm sure I know what you were asking.